# Implement the removeProperty function that takes an object and a property name

Tags: javascript, properties

Implement the removeProperty function that takes an object and a property name and does the following:

If object obj has property prop, it removes the property from the object.
If the property has been removed, it returns true; otherwise it returns false.

What is wrong with this code?

```
function removeProperty(obj,prop) {
if(obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'))
  {
    console.log(obj);
    delete obj.prop;
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
      return false;
    }
}

var obj= {
  name:"John"
};

removeProperty({obj,'name'});
```

Answer (score 10):

The expected code would be :

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
if(prop in obj){
  delete obj[prop];
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The hasOwnProperty() method returns a Boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as own (not inherited) property.So to verify own and inherited properties as well use **in**.

Bracket notation will be the better option than obj.prop.
Since Square bracket notation allows use of characters that can't be used with dot notation(like numbers) and it also allows selection of properties using variables.
In current scenario bracket notation should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code that might be helpful. There are many ways to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>JavaScript Functions</h1>

<p onclick="removeProperty(obj,'name')">This example calls :</p>
<script>
function removeProperty(obj,prop){

if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(obj);
    var b = delete obj.prop;
    console.log(b);
    return true;
  }
  else {
      return false;
    }
}

var obj= {
  name:"John"
};

// removeProperty(obj,'name');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is worked, because testdome only support ECMAScript 5.1, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is due to the argument that you've passed to the `removeProperty` function. It expects two arguments and you passed it 1 which is incorrectly written.

You are trying to pass `{obj, 'name'}` as two arguments when in fact its is a single argument that is an object.

Instead, you should write `removeProperty(obj, 'name');` and change `if(obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'))` to `if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))` because the argument is a variable with a string.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
function removeProperty(obj,prop) {

if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(obj);
    delete obj.prop;
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
      return false;
    }
}

var obj= {
  name:"John"
};

removeProperty(obj,'name');
```

and here is an optimized version:

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
  if (obj[prop] !== undefined) {
    console.log(obj);
    delete obj[prop];
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

var obj= {
  name:'John'
};

removeProperty(obj,'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of stuff at the same problem, but here's the solution to it:

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
  if (obj && obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    delete obj[prop];
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

When they say prop as a property, they mean any key by the name of prop in obj. If you try to access it without the ticks as a value then it should work.

NOTE: I know it's late to answer this question but I didn't find any right one here, so answered anyway. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

this is my approach:

function removeProperty(obj, prop) {

if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){

```
delete obj[prop];
return true;
```

}

return false;
}

Answer (score -1):

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {

  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){

    delete obj[prop];
    return true;
  }


  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    delete obj[prop]
    return true
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit this answer to include an explanation of how it differs from the previous six answers. Perhaps even write up the methodology and the reason for this technique compared to the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
if (obj[prop] != undefined) {
    delete obj[prop];
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
return null;
}
```

Try to check whether a property exists in an object by any of below ways:

1. object.hasOwnProperty(propName)
2. propName in object
3. Comparing with undefined like object.propName !== undefined

Answer (score -1):

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
    if('undefined' !== typeof(obj[prop])){
      delete obj[prop];
      return true;
    }
  return false;
  //return false;
}
```

This is another logic to do this question but not the efficient one as it mutates the original object which is not recommended as good practice.

Another way to solve this will be using spread operator which does not mutates the original object instead creates a copy of new object.

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
   if(obj?[prop]){
     const {prop, ...obj} = obj;
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}

This solution might not work in old versions of javascript before ES6 as spread operator is availaible from ES6.
```

Answer (score -1):

With example method below:

```js
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
  if(prop in obj) {
        delete obj[prop];
        console.log(obj);   //to print out the left over 
        return true ;
    }else{
        return false;
    } 
}

const myObject = {
 name: "John Doe", 
 email:  "john@gmail.com", 
 phone_no: +234-802-894-7884, 
 cc_code: 123
} 

Let result = removeProperty(myObject,  'cc_code') ;
console.log(result);
```